# How can I run an action when a state changes?

Tags: ios, swift, state, swiftui

```
enum SectionType: String, CaseIterable {
    case top = "Top"
    case best = "Best"
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var selection: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        SegmentedControl(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(SectionType.allCases.identified(by: \.self)) { type in
                Text(type.rawValue).tag(type)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I run code (e.g `print("Selection changed to \(selection)")` when the `$selection` state changes? I looked through the docs and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sorry for my answer before, it was incorrect. I have deleted it for now but I am looking into this and will answer as soon as I find out :D

Comment: What is it that you want to do when the selection changes?

Comment: I haven't worked with this enough to say for sure - and will happily delete this comment if way off - but I tried executing a `func` with a `print` in it, even set a breakpoint, and no luck. Yet, when I put SwiftUI code (like creating a `Text("got here")` it worked. Keeping in mid it's **all** beta 1, I'm thinking this will be corrected (or at least better documented) in a later beta.

Comment: @Fogmeister I want to run a function which fetches stories from the Hacker News API

Comment: You might want to try using `@Published` decorator and subscribe to it.

Comment: @DanieleBernardini I haven’t heard of that, is there a docs link that can tell me more?

Comment: Its the combine framework, check the videos from WWDC on Combine

Comment: @DanieleBernardini Thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can't use `didSet` observer on `@State` but you can on an `ObservableObject` property.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class SelectionStore: ObservableObject {
    var selection: SectionType = .top {
        didSet {
            print("Selection changed to \(selection)")
        }
    }

    // @Published var items = ["Jane Doe", "John Doe", "Bob"]
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
import SwiftUI

enum SectionType: String, CaseIterable {
    case top = "Top"
    case best = "Best"
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var store = SelectionStore()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Picker("Selection", selection: $store.selection) {
                ForEach(FeedType.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
                    Text(type.rawValue).tag(type)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            // ForEach(store.items) { item in
            //     Text(item)
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `onReceive`

Comment: And what if I want to change another `@State` property in the ContentView on `didSet`? With your code I stuck in the instance of the SelectionStore

Comment: You can override didSet on a simple struct, no need to use an object.

Answer (score 84):

There are now two new `onChange(of:initial:_:)`'s, one with [zero](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-8wgw9) closure parameters and one with [two](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-4psgg).

Both now also provide the option to opt-in to running the code block when the view initially appears, by using `initial: true` (`false` by default). The former with zero closure parameters is now the new "default" for when you just want to get the new value. The latter with two closure parameters lets you get the old & new value to compare, similar to how we used to do a capture group to get the old value.

**iOS 17.0+**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isLightOn = false

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Light", isOn: $isLightOn)
            .onChange(of: isLightOn) {
                if isLightOn {
                    print("Light is now on!")
                } else {
                    print("Light is now off.")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

---

**iOS 14.0+**

You can use the [`onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) modifier, like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isLightOn = false

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Light", isOn: $isLightOn)
            .onChange(of: isLightOn) { value in
                if value {
                    print("Light is now on!")
                } else {
                    print("Light is now off.")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

---

**iOS 13.0+**

The following as an extension of `Binding`, so you can execute a closure whenever the value changes.

```
extension Binding {
    
    /// When the `Binding`'s `wrappedValue` changes, the given closure is executed.
    /// - Parameter closure: Chunk of code to execute whenever the value changes.
    /// - Returns: New `Binding`.
    func onUpdate(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(get: {
            wrappedValue
        }, set: { newValue in
            wrappedValue = newValue
            closure()
        })
    }
}
```

Used like so for example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isLightOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Light", isOn: $isLightOn.onUpdate(printInfo))
    }
    
    private func printInfo() {
        if isLightOn {
            print("Light is now on!")
        } else {
            print("Light is now off.")
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>This example doesn't *need* to use a separate function. You only need a closure.</sup>

Comment: If you use $isLightOn.animation() for the toggle binding then your side effects in onChange aren't animated as they normally would so I don't think this is the right approach.

Comment: This is the best approach for me. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

### iOS 13+

You can use `onReceive`:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = false

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Selection", isOn: $selection)
            .onReceive(Just(selection)) { selection in
                // print(selection)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved me the day with just that "Just". I had been looking for this for a long time. I needed a delay on a @State variable and with that "Just" this is now really simple and works fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 25):

In iOS 14 there is now a `onChange` modifier you can use like so:

```
SegmentedControl(selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(SectionType.allCases.identified(by: \.self)) { type in
        Text(type.rawValue).tag(type)
    }
}
.onChange(of: selection) { value in
    print("Selection changed to \(selection)")
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is another option if you have a component that updates a `@Binding`. Rather than doing this:

```
Component(selectedValue: self.$item, ...)
```

you can do this and have a little greater control:

```
Component(selectedValue: Binding(
    get: { self.item },
    set: { (newValue) in
              self.item = newValue
              // now do whatever you need to do once this has changed
    }), ... )
```

This way you get the benefits of the binding along with the detection of when the `Component` has changed the value.

Comment: This throws runtime errors: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."

Comment: Love this answer. This pattern has saved my butt a few times.

Comment: To those who want an `extension` of `Binding` for this, see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63289866/9607863). I find it much neater to call.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Binding

```
let textBinding = Binding<String>(
    get: { /* get */ },
    set: { /* set $0 */ }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

### iOS 17+

It has changed again! The one-parameter closure now gives this warning:

> 'onChange(of:perform:)' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: Use `onChange`
> with a two or zero parameter action closure instead.

So, now you write it one of 2 ways:

1. The zero-parameter way.
2. The 2-parameter way.

### Zero-parameter

```
.onChange(of: playState) {
            model.playStateDidChange(state: playState)
        }
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-8wgw9?ref=optimistic-closures.com

### 2-parameter

```
.onChange(of: playState) { oldState, newState in
            model.playStateDidChange(from: oldState, to: newState)
        }
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-4psgg?ref=optimistic-closures.com

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question, but here's the right way to set up `SegmentedControl` (didn't want to post that code as a comment, because it looks ugly). Replace your `ForEach` version with the following code:

```
ForEach(0..<SectionType.allCases.count) { index in 
    Text(SectionType.allCases[index].rawValue).tag(index)
}
```

Tagging views with enumeration cases or even strings makes it behave inadequately – selection doesn't work.

You might also want to add the following after the `SegmentedControl` declaration to ensure that selection works:

`Text("Value: \(SectionType.allCases[self.selection].rawValue)")`

Full version of `body`:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        SegmentedControl(selection: self.selection) {
            ForEach(0..<SectionType.allCases.count) { index in
                Text(SectionType.allCases[index].rawValue).tag(index)
                }
            }

        Text("Value: \(SectionType.allCases[self.selection].rawValue)")
    }
}
```

Regarding your question – I tried adding `didSet` observer to `selection`, but it crashes Xcode editor and generates "Segmentation fault: 11" error when trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

I like to solve this by moving the data into a struct:

```
struct ContentData {
    var isLightOn = false {
        didSet {
            if isLightOn {
                print("Light is now on!")
            } else {
                print("Light is now off.")
            }
            // you could update another var in this struct based on this value
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var data = ContentData()

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Light", isOn: $data.isLightOn)
    }
}
```

The advantage this way is if you decide to update another var in the struct based on the new value in `didSet`, and if you make your binding animated, e.g. `isOn: $data.isLightOn.animation()` then any Views you update that use the other var will animate their change during the toggle. That doesn't happen if you use `onChange`.

E.g. here the list sort order change animates:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentData {
    var ascending = true {
        didSet {
            sort()
        }
    }
    
    var colourNames = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "Yellow", "Black"]
    
    init() {
        sort()
    }
    
    mutating func sort(){
        if ascending {
            colourNames.sort()
        }else {
            colourNames.sort(by:>)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = ContentData()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Sort", isOn:$data.ascending.animation())
            List(data.colourNames, id: \.self) { name in
                Text(name)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```