# didSet for a @Binding var in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Normally we can use `didSet` in swift to monitor the updates of a variable. But it didn't work for a `@Binding` variable. For example, I have the following code:

```
@Binding var text {
   didSet {
       ......
   }
}
```

But the `didSet` is never been called.Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more code?  use `didSet` all the time. The issue is with code you haven't presented.

Comment: DidSet doesn’t get called on @Binding because the binding doesn’t get set. It’s the value wrapped in binding that changes. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve in didSet?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550713/how-can-i-run-an-action-when-a-state-changes/56581087#56581087

Comment: Is it a `UIViewRepresentable`? Then you can use `updateUIView`. `updateUIView` is called every time a binding or state changes.

Answer (score 25):

Instead of `didSet` you can always use `onReceive` (iOS 13+) or `onChange` (iOS 14+):

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        ChildView(counter: $counter)
        Button("Increment") {
            counter += 1
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var counter: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(counter))
            .onReceive(Just(counter)) { value in
                print("onReceive: \(value)")
            }
            .onChange(of: counter) { value in
                print("onChange: \(value)")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You shouldn’t need a `didSet` observer on a `@Binding`.

If you want a `didSet` because you want to compute something else for display when `text` changes, just compute it. For example, if you want to display the count of characters in `text`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var count: Int { text.count }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
            Text(“count: \(count)”)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to observe `text` because you want to make some other change to your data model, then observing the change from your `View` is wrong. You should be observing the change from elsewhere in your model, or in a controller object, not from your `View`. Remember that your `View` is a **value** type, not a reference type. SwiftUI creates it when needed, and might store multiple copies of it, or no copies at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know what you mean. And it works in `body` function. But in my case, I'm not inheriting from a `View`. Instead I'm inheriting from a `UIViewRepresentable`. It's easier for me if `didSet` works.

Comment: `UIViewRepresentable` is a sub-protocol of `View`. Any type that conforms to `UIViewRepresentable` conforms to `View`.

Comment: This does not allow for a case where you want to refresh the view when the value of the bound variable changes. In the above snippet, "count" would need to be Published, but you cannot have the Published wrapper on a computed property.

Comment: (Re: my earlier comment, I am referring to a case where the "text" Binding variable and the "count" computed variable are managed within a ViewModel)

Comment: No, `count` does not need to be `Published`, because it is computed on demand entirely from values tracked by SwiftUI. The `count` getter calls the `text` getter, so when the program accesses `count`, SwiftUI notices the dependency on `text`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to wrap the property in an `ObservableObject`:

```swift
final class TextStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = "" {
        didSet { ... }
   }
}
```

And then use that `ObservableObject`'s property as a binding variable in your view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = TextStore()
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $store.text)
    }
}
```

`didSet` will now be called whenever `text` changes.

---

Alternatively, you could create a sort of makeshift `Binding` value:

```swift
TextField("", text: Binding<String>(
    get: {
        return self.text
    },
    set: { newValue in
        self.text = newValue
        ...
    }
))
```

Just note that with this second strategy, the `get` function will be called every time the view is updated. I wouldn't recommend using this approach, but nevertheless it's good to be aware of it.