# In-App Purchase callback function to store in CoreData

Tags: swift, swiftui, in-app-purchase

I have a `ContentView` which uses an `EnvironmentObject`. After an In-App Purchase this object should be saved to the `CoreData`. My `ContentView` looks something like this:

```
//ContentView
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @StateObject var storeManager: StoreManager


    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            purchaseAndSaveToCoreData()
        }, label: {
            Text("buy for 100")
        })
    }
    
    func purchaseAndSaveToCoreData() {
        //Open the storeManager and do the purchase
        storeManager.purchaseProduct(product: storeManager.myProducts[0])
        
        //Wait for the purchase callback and then save an object from the EnvironmentObject modelData to CoreData here <- How?
        let newItemToStore = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItemToStore.name = modelData.name
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}
```

And my `StoreManager` class is this:

```
//StoreManager
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class StoreManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    
    //FETCH PRODUCTS
    //[...] Fetching Process goes here
    
    
    //HANDLE TRANSACTIONS
    @Published var transactionState: SKPaymentTransactionState?
    
    func purchaseProduct(product: SKProduct) {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        } else {
            print("User can't make payment.")
        }
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                transactionState = .purchasing
            case .purchased:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .purchased
                //Can I use my environmentObject modelData here?
            case .restored:
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .restored
            case .failed, .deferred:
                print("Payment Queue Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error))")
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .failed
            default:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func restoreProducts() {
        print("Restoring products ...")
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, the purchase takes place. But I can't get a crucial thing to work. How can I wait inside the `ContentView` for a callback of the `paymentQueue` when it's in `.purchased` mode?
I thought about the `@Published transactionState` and wanted to use it inside the `purchaseAndSaveToCoreData()` function like this:

```
//ContentView
//[...]

storeManager.purchaseProduct(product: storeManager.myProducts[0])
        
//Wait for the purchase callback and then save an object from the EnvironmentObject modelData to CoreData here <- How?
if storeManager.transactionState == .purchased {
   let newItemToStore = Item(context: viewContext)
   newItemToStore.name = modelData.name
   do {
      try viewContext.save()
   } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
}
```

But the `if` statement runs of course immediately after the `storeManager.purchaseProduct()` function and doesn't fire. I know the right timing to look for is inside the `StoreManager` at the `case .purchased`. But I can't use my `EnvironmentObject` there. I'm relatively new to Swift so I might be missing a key feature about Callbacks, States or triggering functions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer pointed me in the right direction: [How can I run an action when a state changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63289866/7946387)

I changed the button in my `ContentView` to:

```
Button(action: {
   purchaseAndSaveToCoreData()
}, label: {
   Text("buy for 100")
})
.onChange(of: storeManager.transactionState) { transactionState in
   if transactionState == .purchased {
      saveVirginKeyToCoreData()
   }
}
```

The `onChange` attribute listens for the state change of `transactionState`.